# WPF Threading Backgroundworker issue

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have two different background thread who does similar thing but at different time in my WPF application. both are right now independent background worker.

1) first thread runs when you launch application, it downloads all images from connected printer to PC location.

2) second thread does the same thing  when use click on some link in my application.

As both worker are independent, even though first thread's downloading process are still running, if user click on link the second thread start their work too

What I would like to do is, when user click on 2nd thread, is there any way I will know about status of first thread ? I mean if i know that first thread is doing it's work then I don't want to even start second thread. I need only second thread when first one got cancelled by some other reason.

I heard about Mutex but I dont know how it works. Pls share ur idea and some example if you know how to handle this.

Thanks

Dee

Comment: In BackgroundWorker thread there is an event called RunWorkerCompleted which can tell if the first thread is complete or not also if it cancelled or not. Based on the you can initiate the second thread.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For something like this I would probably just use a plain flag variable, `bool DownloadActive;`, or something, in my main form code, which is set to false by the background worker's completion event and then checked when a link is clicked.

Comment: Why are you even using threads in the first place? There is no CPU processing. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Ganesh, I have two diff class completely independent. RunWorkerCompleted fires in first class, but how other class would know (which is nothing but Model when user click on link), that initial background thread is still running or done.

Comment: If I dont use background worker in first place then application wont even start before it's done with downloading of images from printer. Images what if there 1000 images.

Comment: Why do you have even have two different background thread that do similar things if you only one one running.  Simple one background worker that does both.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you make a manager to handle the background threads. Maybe something like this:

```
interface IDownloadManager
{
    bool IsRunning {get; }
    void Start();
    void Stop();

    event Action DownloadStarted;
    event Action DownloadCompleted;
    event Action<Image> ImageDownloaded;
}
```

This manager should handle the starting/stopping and monitoring of the backgroundworkers. That way, you won't start more than one download process.